# How to correctly display modal popup window with modal bootstrap in react?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am currently working on displaying a modal popup window by utilizing react modal bootstrap but it seems like something is wrong in my code. Here are my codes. I checked the following website as a reference for the codes. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ModalList from './ModalList';
import '../css/MyPlacesEntry.css';
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


class MyPlacesEntry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  toggleModal() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: true
    });
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
              {/* {console.log("111111", this)} */}
              <div className="post-preview" >
                <h2 className="post-menu" onClick={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>{this.props.i.menu}</h2>
                <ModalList item={this.props.i} showModal={this.state.showModal} close={this.close.bind(this)} />
                <h5 className="post-comment">{this.props.i.comment}</h5>
                <p className="post-meta">Posted by&nbsp;
                <a href="#">{this.props.i.gmailAccount}</a>
                  &nbsp;on january 23, 2018</p>
                <hr />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyPlacesEntry;
```

I was trying to send showModal as true to ModalList with onClick event but I am not sure if it is correctly coded.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyPlacesEntry from './MyPlacesEntry';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ModalList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal {...this.props} bsSize="large" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">{this.props.title}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <p>
            price
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.props.price}
          </p>
          <p>
            menu
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.props.menu}
          </p>
          <p>
            comment
          </p>
          <p>
            {this.props.comment}
          </p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Those codes are pretty much from the reference page but I am not exactly sure which code should be implemented to display the modal popup window. I would appreciate if you could solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use React-Bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal). At this link, you can find examples of how to use modals or other things.
By doing this,you can use Modal as a react component like: `<Modal/>`